# How are tags managed on websites to optimize them for search engines

Tags: html, search, tags, search-engine

Like here on Stack Overflow, when one asks a question, that question is now a tag of some page, is a new page created inside the the server with the name of the a tag so that search engines can find it, how does this work?

If no pages are created, where is this data of all the tags kept?

I see for this very page, Stack overflow haas this facebook tag.

```
<meta name="og:description" content="Like here on stack over flow, when one asks a question, that question is ">
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored in a database.

The pages are generated by having the [HTTP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aWeb_server_software) invoke a piece of software which examines the URL, fetches the appropriate data from the database, and outputs some HTML.

There are numerous ways to do this including [psgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSGI), [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI), [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), and [wsgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface).

Comment: So search engines are indexing a database for this pages?

Comment: No. Search engines are indexing URLs. They don't care (and can't know) how the HTTP server determines what to return when a given URL is requested.

Comment: Ok i see the tools you've provided are of perl, is the one for PHP?

Comment: Only `psgi` is Perl specific. PHP can be invoked using FastCGI, CGI mod_php and probably others.

Comment: ok, So for every activity asked, i can store the details of this activity in aome db table named tags, let's say i have the facebook tag og:title:Test1, How does facebook display this tag or google have a record of this pages if this pages are not realy pages but 1 page with dynamic tags?

Comment: They are really pages. Each page has a URL. Clients don't care and cannot know if the HTTP server got the page from a file, by generating it from data in a database, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

that information used when you post a link to this page to facebook. just try it and you will see the result.
details: http://ogp.me/

Comment: I know what that tag is for, but my question is did Stackflow create a new page when i asked this question with this tag?